# EC2 Windows server recovery options if disconnected from domain

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

So, I have these Windows 2016 servers. Everything is domain joined.

They are running in Amazon EC2.

I'm doing some system hardening, using recommendations from CIS. (For reference, the PDF is titled "CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2016 RTM (Release 1607) Benchmark" and can be downloaded here: https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/microsoft_windows_server/ )

There is one recommendation for hardening that seem to be a Bad Idea(TM) in EC2. That one is CIS section 2.3.1.1, *Ensure 'Accounts: Administrator account status' is set to 'Disabled'*

The concern I have with this is this paragraph from the same section in the CIS document:

> Maintenance issues can arise under certain circumstances if you disable the Administrator account. For example, if the secure channel between a member computer and the domain controller fails in a domain environment for any reason and there is no other local Administrator account, you must restart in safe mode to fix the problem that broke the secure channel.

In EC2, you can't boot to safe mode. There's no physical console. The only recovery option available is "Directory Services Restore Mode" which isn't the same as Safe Mode.

I've taken other hardening steps to ensure the local Administrator is hardened.

What is a recommended the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referring to the default admin account called Administrator. You will want to create a new local admin account that does not have the username "Administrator" and then you can safely disable the account named "Administrator." The spirit of CIS 2.3.1.1 is to remove this default account and create something unique to your company and not use the default username provided by the EC2 instance.

Comment: ok, this makes sense and is straightforward. thanks

Comment: you bet, and to further clarify your warning you referenced is that is you don't have any local admin you're out of luck if the instance can no longer talk to a DC, so just make sure you know that local admin login you created.

Comment: @JDS Did everything end up working out for you?

Comment: yes. I created a new user in the admins group named "myadmin" and renamed the built-in admin to "builtin-admin" and disabled him.